# Finding $v_y$ in system of equations.

Tags: calculus

$$\begin{cases}u^2+v^2+x^2-y^2=1 \\ u^2-v^2-x^2-y^2=4 \end{cases}$$

I want to know $v_y$.

where $u(x,y),v(x,y)$ are functions of $x,y$ and smooth.

To do this I first did:

$$\begin{cases}2uu_x+2vv_x+2x=0 ,& 2uu_y+2vv_y-2y=0 \\ 2uu_x-2vv_x-2x=0 ,& 2uu_y-2vv_y-2y=0 \end{cases}$$

Maybe I can solve it now but I dont think this is the proper way?

Comment: What are $u, v, x, y$? Functions? Vectors? Numbers?

Comment: Since I can take partial derivatives these (u,v) are functions of x,y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By subtraction,

$$2v^2+2x^2=-3$$ and $v$ does not depend on $y$.

Comment: okay, but in general with these kind of equations, how to solve it properly? Is it connected to Inverse function theorem

Comment: @Jale'dejaleuffnejale: this is not what your question was asking. Should I answer for every equation in the world ?

Comment: No of course, I am sorry, thank you, good days.